# Seaborn, violin plot with one data per column

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to combine this violin plot http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html (fourth example with split=True) with this one http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/elaborate_violinplot.html.

Actually, I have a dataFrame with a column `Success` (Yes or No) and several data column. For example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Success": 50 * ["Yes"] + 50 * ["No"], 
     "A": np.random.randint(1, 7, 100), 
     "B": np.random.randint(1, 7, 100)}
)

    A  B Success
0   6  4     Yes
1   6  2     Yes
2   1  1     Yes
3   1  2     Yes
.. .. ..     ...
95  4  4      No
96  2  1      No
97  2  6      No
98  2  3      No
99  2  1      No
```

I would like to plot a violin plot for each data column. It works with :

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.violinplot(data=df[["A", "B"]], inner="quartile", bw=.15)
```

But now, I would like to split the violin according to the `Success` column. But, using `hue="Success"` I got an error with `Cannot use 'hue' without 'x' or 'y'`. Thus how can I do to plot the violin plot by splitting according to "Success" column ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If understand your question correctly, you need to reshape your dataframe to have it in long format:

```
df = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['A', 'B'], id_vars='Success')
sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', hue='Success', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: It does not seem to work anymore -- I mean running this code does not produce this image, but 4 violin plots

Comment: @CharlyEmpereur-mot to make it look like on this page you need to set the parameter `split` to True. From the docs: "when using hue nesting with a variable that takes two levels, setting split to True will draw half of a violin for each level. This can make it easier to directly compare the distributions"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to adapt an [example](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_with_seaborn.html) of a violin plot over a DataFrame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Success": 50 * ["Yes"] + 50 * ["No"], 
                   "A": np.random.randint(1, 7, 100), 
                   "B": np.random.randint(1, 7, 100)})
sns.violinplot(df.A, df.B, df.Success, inner="quartile", split=True)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image: Seaborn violin graph over Pandas DataFrame]

Clearly, it still needs some work: the A scale should be sized to fit a single half-violin, for example.